# Go to a link by using it's parameters?

Tags: html, url

I have a url and the button doesn't work right so i'm having to input the values into the url. I know it's possible to take the values and put them into the url to get to the page. How is this done? For example

```
<form method="get" action="https://example.url.com/courses/enrol/manual/manage.php" id="enrolusersbutton-1">
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Enroll users">
<input type="hidden" name="enrolid" value="276">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="92">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You should be doing a post request if you are sending over enrolid and id to your url. On the php side, you can get the id and enrolid via the http headers
https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/retrieve-html-form-data-with-php/

Comment: There's actually no data being sent anywhere. Maybe I didn't explain it well enough, I was kind of in a hurry. This is a button within Moodle that is supposed to enroll users into a course. The button is broken for whatever reason. But, there is a way to take the example link, and put in the parameters to get to a new page that shows a page to enroll users instead of a button that uses a pop up display. So the URL should look something like example.url.com/courses/enrol/manual/manage.php?value="276"?value="92"...but this doesn't get me there for some reason.

Comment: Ah now I get it. It seems to work fine in jsfiddle. Hard to guess what could be wrong without it being reproducible.